# MS Access 03 Query using Yes/No Data Type

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access..
**AccessKey**
AccessCardID
Distributed (yes/no)

On my form is a combo box with 10 Access Cards. I need help setting up a query where if guest A gets Access Card #1, the user will only be able to choose from Access Cards #2-#10, for guest B, c, and so on, until guest A returns Access Card #1.
so far the the query i have is

```
SELECT AccessCardID  
FROM AccessKey  
WHERE Distributed = False;
```

Here is my new code for After update

```
Private Sub AccessKeyNo_AfterUpdate()
If MsgBox("Do you want to assign Access Key" & Me.AccessKeyNo & "?", _
        vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Me.GuestAccessKeyID = Me.AccessKeyNo
    Me.MyCheckBox = Not IsNull(Me.GuestAccessKeyID)
    Me.AccessKeyNo.Requery
End If
End Sub
```

My new query

```
SELECT AccessKey.AccessKeyID
FROM AccessKey LEFT JOIN Guest ON AccessKey.AccessKeyID=Guest.GuestAccessKeyID
WHERE (((Guest.GuestAccessKeyID) Is Null));
```

And the On current for the form

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.MyCheckBox = Not IsNull(Me.GuestAccessKeyID)

If IsNull(Me![GuestID]) Then
DoCmd.GoToControl "GuestFirstName"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On the form, if I go to a new guest AccessCardId #1 can still be selected, whereas I dont want it to show in the combo box.

Comment: Just change the query to `WHERE Distributed = False`, as David McEwing says.

Comment: If i give guest A, card #1, then create a new guest, card#1 is still there

Comment: Did you mark the card as distributed after giving it to A?

Comment: You might like to consider a little code in the After Update event of the combo.

Comment: No. I would have to open the table to do that though, right? I was hoping there was a way for it to check distributed without having to open the table

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of, as I dont know how I would right that code

Comment: If you close Access and reopen it does it appear correctly?  If so you might just need a macro to rebind the new guest form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not like writing code, you can use a subform and set the record source to your table, AccessKey. Alternatively you can write a little code, say:

```
Private Sub NameOfComboHere_AfterUpdate()
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
    If MsgBox("Do you want to assign " & Me.NameOfComboHere & "?", _
            vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE AccessKey SET Distributed = True " _
            & "WHERE AccessCardID = " & Me.NameOfComboHere
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        If db.RecordsAffected = 1 Then
            MsgBox Me.NameOfComboHere & " has been assigned."
        End If
    End If

    Me.NameOfComboHere.Requery
End Sub
```

There are a few notes. This assumes that the combobox has a bound column of AccessCardID  and that AccessCardID  is numeric. It also assumes that you have a reference to Microsoft DAO 3.x Object library. A subform may be the best bet.

EDIT based on Comments

Let us say you have a card id in the guest table, first, add a little code to the Current event for the form:

```
Me.MyCheckBox = Not IsNull(Me.GuestAccessCard)
```

This will set the checkbox to false if there is no card id and to true if there is an id.

You will need to change the query for the combobox to:

```
SELECT AccessCardID 
FROM AccessKey 
LEFT JOIN Guests 
ON AccessKey.AccessCardID = Guest.GuestAccessCard
WHERE Guest.GuestAccessCard Is Null
```

Then the After Update event would run:

```
Private Sub NameOfComboHere_AfterUpdate()
    If MsgBox("Do you want to assign " & Me.NameOfComboHere & "?", _
            vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Me.GuestAccessCard = Me.NameOfComboHere
        Me.MyCheckBox = Not IsNull(Me.GuestAccessCard)
        ''The data will have to be saved for the
        ''combo to update with the new data
        If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
        Me.NameOfComboHere.Requery
    End If

End Sub
```

And do not forget to set the GuestAccessCard to Null when the checkbox is unticked and requery the combo.

Comment: Thank you!!. My last question, when guest A is done with access card #1, and returns it. How do I go about putting it back in the combo box?

Comment: How do you want to do it? Another combo? Another form?

Comment: Could you do a check box to say something like Access card returned? If not, another combo box.

Comment: You could have a checkbox if you had a guestid associated with the card, but you don't, so the second combobox is exactly the reverse of everything you did for the first, that is True every where you had False. Get back if you run into problems.

Comment: BTW, this is where things get a little awkward, because you do not have a guestid on the card table, someone can say that card 1 was given back, but they meant to say card 2.

Comment: If I added GuestId to the card table would that change everything youve shown me so far?

Comment: If a guest could have more than one card, then you add the guestid to the card table, if a guest can have one card from now until eternity, you can add the cardid to the guest table. It would change things a bit, in that you would update a table with an ID, rather than setting a flag, but it would also mean that you coud have a checkbox on your form to say that the guest had a card. It would only take a little code.

Comment: The guest can only have one card for the duration of there stay. So i could now add a check box to my form and it would then release that card number back into my combo box? What would that code look like?

Comment: I have added some more notes. Play around with these ideas.

Comment: @Remou once again I thank you for all your help, but the updated information is not working. A couple of questions...what is the Me.GuestAccessCard? When I plug in the new code that line keeps giving me a compile error.

Comment: It is what ever you called the field that will store the AccessCardID in the Guest table and it needs to be in the recordset that the form is based on. It will be if the form is based on a table, but you will have to fiddle about a bit, if it is based on a query.

Comment: Does MyCheckBox need to be in the Guest table as well? Ok, so I have the updated code in place, but if i give GUEST A card #1, its not removing it from my combo box as it was before.

Comment: MyCheckBox is an unbound checkbox, the value is set in the Current event of the form. Did you change the query for the recordset? These have to match: ON AccessKey.AccessCardID = Guest.GuestAccessCard, so put in whatever names you used to store the ID.

Comment: No, it looks fine to me. Just check that the AccessKeyID is being written to your Guest table. If you want to upload your mdb to a file sharing site, I will take a look at it.

Comment: What is a good file sharing site? or Could I just zip it to you?

Comment: You can use the PM on www.lessthandot.com

Comment: Once a member of lessthandot.com what do i do?

Comment: I didn't think you had to join. Look here http://forum.lessthandot.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=73 and choose `send private message`.

Comment: Where is the send private message??

Comment: When you click the link can you not see send private message on the left hand site under Contact?

Comment: No. But I do get Error on the page at the bottom left

Comment: Here is a thread: http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=12043&start=25 you should see PM under each users avatar.

Comment: Send a PM, it will allow you to attach a file.

Comment: I dont see an attach file field anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set Distributed to False in the above query so that you get the list of cards which have not been distributed yet.

Comment: Sorry, I had False in my query but put true above.

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely misunderstanding the situation here, but it seems to me that you don't want to have a Boolean field in the table with your cards to indicate if it's checked out -- all you need is a field in your Guests table where you enter the card number. Then you can tell which cards are available with a left join against the card numbers that are in use:

```
  SELECT Cards.CardNumber
  FROM Cards LEFT JOIN Guests ON Cards.CardNumber = Guests.CardNumber
  WHERE Guests.CardNumber Is Null
```

This would mean that there's only ever one place where the information is stored (in the Guests table). You could also put a unique index on the CardNumber field in the Guests table (allow Nulls) so you could never assign the same card to two guests.

This may be the way you are doing things, or the way Remou has suggested, but I got too confused by all the convoluted back and forth!

Comment: I think you may have missed the comments where this approach was discussed and decided upon, hence the revisions.

Comment: I'm still seeing a checkbox in there, and not knowing why it should exist.

Comment: Because that is what he wants. This whole thing got very complicated (see previous questions) and I believe in leading, not driving.

Comment: Well, the complexity is why I couldn't get the point. It seems like a very simple situation to me, and that he's making it overcomplicated because his schema is wrong (insofar as I understand it).

Comment: Yes. And in a previous question I suggested a different schema, but the OP chose not to go that way. sometimes it is necessary to find out in steps why standard schemas are standard.